# What is the significance of proving the integrability of monotonic functions?

Tags: calculus

The complete question is

What is the significance of proving the integrability of monotonic functions when it was proved the integrability of a general one?

Doesn't the integrability of a general function implies that of a monotonic one?

I'm reading Calculus I, which says:

**Theorem 1.12:** If $g$ is monotonic on a closed interval [a,b], then $g$ is integrable  on $[a,b]$.

But by **Theorem 1.9** we stablished the existence of the integral of a general function $f$ bounded on a closed interval iff $\underline{\mathbf{I}}(f) = \bar{\mathbf{I}}(f)$.

I don't think the proof of **Theorem 1.12** seems to care about the character of $g$ as a monotonic function. It looks like one can stuck that proof with Theorem 1.19 and it would work equally well.

Certainly a general function $f$ whose domain is $[a,b]$ cannot be said to be monotonic, but, I think, one always can choose an arbitrary partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ with $n$ subintervals $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ where $f$ is either increasing or decreasing and therefore monotonic on $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$.

In the way I'm (mis)understanding this, I would show the integrability of a general function $f$ on a closed interval (Theorem 1.19 does that), and then show that a set of monotonic functions is a subset of a set of general ones, which implies they are integrable too.

Well, I haven't dedicaded further thoughts to the last proposal, but I haven't been able to see the difference between the two cases either.

Comment: "Doesn't the integrability of a general function implies that of a monotonic one?" Obviously yes. You're not asking what you want to ask and I can't figure out what you want to ask either.

Comment: @GitGud Apostol proves 1.9 and 1.12 as two different things (as it's supposed to be), but if one reads the proofs, it looks like they are interchangeable. That's why I'm puzzled. If the proof of 1.12 can be copied/pasted as a proof for 1.9 and viceversa, where is the connection or the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that **1.9** has a complicated **if** while **1.12** does not have.

It is usually hard to show $\underline{\mathbf{I}}(f) = \bar{\mathbf{I}}(f)$

Example of non-integrable functions is [Nowhere continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function)

In general, proving integrability is hard. while 1.12 make it easy.

Comment: Well, the approach taken by Apostol to show that $\underline{\mathbf{I}}(f) = \bar{\mathbf{I}}(f)$ is by approximating a function $f$ with step functions from below and from above, such that the integral exists when the supremum of the smaller function = the infimum of the larger one. That's the way both 1.9 and 1.12 are proved although with 1.12 he uses another theorem (1.31) that makes it a more straightforward proof.

Comment: @Jazz in 1.9, for each function, you need to calculate suremum and infimum, while in 1.12 the theory has already used that. You may say 1.12 stands for all functions. But you should know that there are cases which 1.12 cannot handle. Is your question about knowing these cases?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I haven't explained myself well. Although I see there are cases where 1.12 does not hold, what I'm not understanding is the difference between 1.9 and 1.12 aside that $f$ is a general function and $g$ is a monotonic one. Both proofs look valid and interchangeable between the theorems, so to me it looks that a definition of a monotonic function and something tying them to the general ones is enough. Then, if 1.12 does not apply in some cases, neither 1.9. I see a connection between the 1.9 and 1.12 that is lacking (I can't see it I guess).

Comment: @Jazz: If you pick an arbitrary function $f$, it may or may not be true that the upper or lower integrals are equal. If they happen to be equal, then $f$ is integrable, otherwise not. And in general it might not be easy to decide which of the cases that occurs. What the other theorem is saying is that if you pick an arbitrary *monotonic* function things are really simple: then we know that the upper and lower integrals *must* be equal.

Comment: @Jazz theorem 1.9 makes your job much easier. consider cases where conditions of 1.9 are not met. However your are considering only cases where you can implement 1.9 piece wise but the number of these pieces must be finite. What if the number of those pieces are infinite? Or what if the function g is $\infty$ at a? such as $\frac1x$ at $[0,5]$. In 1.9 , g has expensive condition of having boundary. So this theorem cannot be used when g is infinite at a or b.

Comment: @Arashium You meant 1.12 makes things easier, right? I think I'm getting the idea. It would have to do with the constraint in the boundedness imposed by 1.9 which makes it not applicable with certain function. There is where we invoked 1.12 to deal with such functions like $\frac{1}{x}$, where there is no way to approximate it from above/below near the origin. Since 1.12 is ''more specific'', we can use it as argument when a function can't be integrated.

Comment: @HansLundmark I think I'm beginning to see the light at the end of the tunnel (:. One thing that the proof of 1.12 states that the proof of 1.9 does not is that the step functions approximating $g$ (monotonic) are functions of $g$ itself. Since we know where $g$ goes, we can be more careful in choosing the approximating step functions from above/below (which, at the end, give us the lower and upper integrals). Since 1.9 is kind of vague, we can't be sure whether the approximating step functions are the right ones. The argument behind the two cases (1.9 and 1.12) goes like that, right?

Comment: @Jazz sorry for my mistake. $\frac1x$ is not integrable in [0,5] however $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable although it is $+\infty$ at $x=5$ which only satisfies 1.9 and not 1.12

Comment: @Arashium No problem (:. I see that $\frac{1}{x}$ can't be enclosed near the origin, so neither 1.9 nor 1.12 are satisfied. But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is monotonic decreasing, shouldn't 1.12 also be satisfied?

Comment: @Jazz 1.12 is not satisfied since $\frac1{\sqrt x}$ is not monotonic on [0,5]. It is monotonic only (0,5] which excludes zero. To be monotonic, a function needs to be defined on all point of the domain. The same reason why $\frac1x$ does not satisfy 1.12 . it is not monotonic on [0,5] too.